# Required $class definition for all the Jenkins parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

How do I get to know all the $class definitions for all the parameters available in the Jenkins.

For an example, I have $class definitions for NodeParameter & String Parameter. Likewise, I want for all the available Jenkins parameters. Pls do share.

[
$class: 'NodeParameterValue', name: 'HOST', labels: ["${env.HOSTNAME}"], nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']
 ],
[
$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'RELEASE_VERSION', value: "main"                            ],

Comment: Any udpate on this? Pls help!

Comment: Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Any update on this.